# NOT operation on integer value

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, tilde

I knew that ~ operator does NOT operation. But I could not make out the output of the following program (which is -65536). What exactly is happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int  b = 0xFFFF;
  printf("%d",~b);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you already know exactly what it does what is ur question than

Comment: @suspectus Please don't add the C tag to questions with the C++ tag or vice versa. These are different languages. If you believe a question is C and not C++ and incorrectly tagged as C++, you should remove the C++ tag when adding the C tag.

Comment: @aaronman If it is NOT of 'b' .. then output should be 0 but why -65536

Comment: Your integer is a signed integer not an unsigned integer

Comment: @dukeling different languages but the above code will compile in both. The answers will apply to both. The OP specified c++ else I would have removed c++ tag.

Comment: I think you are assuming that `operator~` is a *logical* `NOT` operation.  It is actually a *binary* `NOT` operation.  Big difference.

Comment: *"I knew that ~ operator does NOT operation."* - Now you just need to know how twos complement works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign the 16-bit value `0xffff` to the 32-bit integer `b`, the variable `b` actually becomes `0x0000ffff`. This means when you do the *bitwise complement* it becomes `0xffff0000` which is the same as decimal `-65536`.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming 32-bit integers

```
int  b = 0xFFFF; => b = 0x0000FFFF
~b = 0xFFFF0000
```

The top bit is now set.  Assuming [2s complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), this means we have a negative number.  Inverting the other bits then adding one gives `0x00010000` or `65536`

Answer (score 2):

The ~ operator in C++ is the bitwise NOT operator. It is also called the bitwise complement. This is flipping the bits of your **signed** integer.

For instance, if you had

```
 int b = 8;
 // b in binary = 1000
 // ~b = 0111
```

This will flip the bits that represent the initial integer value provided.

Comment: ~b = 0111 only if int is 4 bits.  It most likely be 1111111111110111 in binary, assuming 32 bit integer

Comment: Right but he didn't provide any information on the architecture

Answer (score 2):

It is doing a bitwise complement, this output may help you understand what is going on better:

```
std::cout <<  std::hex << " b: " << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) <<  b
           << " ~b: " <<  (~b) << " -65536: " << -65536 << std::endl ;
```

the result that I receive is as follows:

```
b: 0000ffff ~b: ffff0000 -65536: ffff0000
```

So we are setting the lower 16 bits to `1` which gives us `0000ffff` and then we do a complement which will set the lower 16 bits to `0` and the upper 16 bits to `1` which gives us `ffff0000` which is equal to `-65536` in decimal.

In this case since we are working with bitwise operations, examining the data in hex gives us some insight into what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

The result depends on how signed integers are represented on your platform. The most common representation is a 32-bit value using "2s complement" arithmetic to represent negative values. That is, a negative value `-x` is represented by the same bit pattern as the unsigned value `2^32 - x`.

In this case, the original bit pattern has the lower 16 bits set:

```
0x0000ffff
```

The bitwise negation clears those bits and sets the upper 16 bits:

```
0xffff0000
```

Interpreting this as a negative number gives the value `-65536`.

Usually, you'll want to use unsigned types when you're messing around with bitwise arithmetic, to avoid this kind of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment:

> If it is NOT of 'b' .. then output should be 0 but why -65536

Suggests that you are expecting the result of:

```
uint32_t  x = 0xFFFF;
uint32_t y = ~x;
```

to be `0`.

That would be true for a *logical* not operation, such as:

```
uint32_t x = 0xFFFF;
uint32_t y = !x;
```

...but `operator~` is not a *logical* NOT, but a *bitwise* not.  There is a big difference.

A logical returns 0 for non-0 values (or false for true values), and 1 for 0 values.

But a bitwise not reverses each bit in a given value.  So a binary NOT of `0xF`:

```
0x0F:  00000000 11111111
~0x0F: 11111111 00000000
```

Is not zero, but 0xF0.

Answer (score -1):

For every binary number in the integer, a bitwise NOT operation turns all 1s into 0s, and all 0s are turned to 1s.

So hexadecimal `0xFFFF` is binary `1111 1111 1111 1111` (Each hexadecimal character is 4 bits, and F, being 15, is full 1s in all four bits)

You set a 32 bit integer to that, which means it's now:

`0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111`

You then NOT it, which means it's:

`1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000`

The topmost bit is the signing bit (whether it's positive or negative), so it gives a negative number.